# how to prove that this determinant is a polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $n\times n$. I am wondering how to prove that $\det(A+xB)$ is a polynomial function of $x$ ? does anyone has a (simple if possible) proof of this fact? What would be the degree of this polynomial?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how you define determinant, it is more or less obvious that for an $n \times n$ matrix $M$, $\det(M)$ is a polynomial of total degree $n$ in the entries of $M$.  If the entries of $M$ are linear functions of a variable $x$, that implies the determinant is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ in $x$.

If $B$ has rank $r$, then Gaussian elimination  provides an invertible matrix $G$ such that $GB$ has only $r$ nonzero rows.  Now $\det(A+xB) = \det(G)^{-1} \det(GA + xGB)$, and in the expansion of 
$\det(GA + xGB)$ it is clear that there are no nonzero terms with more than $r$ $x$'s.  Therefore $\det(A+xB)$ has degree at most $r$.

Answer (score 2):

Proceed by induction:

**Base case, $n=2$:**

$$
\begin{align*}A+xB$ &= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}+xb_{11} & a_{12}+xb_{12} \\ a_{21}+xb_{21} & a_{22}+xb_{22} \end{pmatrix} \\
\det A+xB &= \left(a_{11}+xb_{11}\right)\left(a_{22}+xb_{22}\right) - \left(a_{12}+xb_{12}\right)\left(a_{21}+xb_{21}\right) \\
 &= a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}+\left(a_{22}b_{11}+a_{11}b_{22}-a_{21}b_{12}-a_{12}b_{21}\right)x+b_{11}b_{22}x^2.
\end{align*}$$

**Induction step:**
Assume the property holds true for all matrices of size $n\times n$. Then, for $A,B$ of order $n+1$:

$$\det A+xB = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k+1}\left(a_{1k}+xb_{1k}\right)\det M_{1k},$$
where $M_{1k}$ is the minor formed by excluding the first row and the $k$th column of $A+xB$.

Since $M_{1k}$ is $n\times n$, its determinant is a polynomial in $x$, and the result is clearly a polynomial in $x$ with a degree at most one greater than that of $M_{1k}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the matrices are $\;n\times n\;$:

$$A=(a_{ij})\;,\;\;B=(b_{ij})\implies A+xB=(a_{ij}+xb_{ij})\implies$$

$$\det (A+xB):=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}Syg(\sigma)\cdot \left(a_{1\sigma(1)}+xb_{1\sigma(1)}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot \left(a_{n\sigma(n)}+xb_{n\sigma(n)}\right)\;---$$

indeed, a polynomial in $\;x\;$ of degree $\;n\;$ (unless the main diagonal of $\;B\;$ has zeros. In this last  case, we can only say the polynomial is of degree at most $\;n\;$)

Comment: ...Of degree $n$?

Comment: Unless the main diagonal of $\;B\;$ has zeroes, yes: of course, @user63181 . Just take the product corresponding to the identity permutation and you already get a non-zero product times $\;x^n\;$ ...

Comment: What about $$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\qquad?$$

Comment: I think that the result should depend on the rank of $B$ and the polynomial has degree rank of $B$.

Comment: Zeroes on the main diagonal is not a good criterion for degree. Take for example $B$ with zeros on the main diagonal and $1$s on the off diagonal, the degree is $2$. Take $B$ with $1$ for every coefficient, this gives the zero polynomial! (For certain $A$). You can say the degree is less than $n$ if for every permutation $\sigma$ one of $b_{i\sigma(i)}$ is $0$, else not a lot (I think).

Comment: Well, no: the only $\;1$'s matrix $\;B\;$ does *not* necessarily give the zero polynomial (do a $\;2\times2\;$ example. For the zero polynomial you\d need also that $\;\det A=0\;$ and that $\;tr A=tr B\;$), though it gives a polynomial of degree at most $\;n-1\;$ . Yes, it is messier than I first thought. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be the answer depends decisively on $\;\text{rank}\,B\;$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A = (a_{i,j}) $ $B = (b_{i,j})$.

Then by definition of determinant $$\text{det}(A +xB) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\biggl(a_{1 \sigma(1)} + x b_{1 \sigma(1)}\biggr)\cdot \biggl(a_{2 \sigma(2)} + x b_{2 \sigma(2)}\biggr)\ldots \biggl(a_{n \sigma(n)} + x b_{n \sigma(n)}\biggr)$$ and this is a polynomial in $x$